# Discriminant of number field is less than discriminant of a root

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

reading a proof of a result regarding number fields in some moment it is state that
$$|\Delta_K| \leq |\Delta_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(u)|$$
where $K$ is a cubic field with only one real inclusion, $u$ is the fundamental unit of $K$ and $\Delta$ is the discriminant.

I don't know why this is true and if it is true in general or is it something about this particular case, but I don't know how to compare discriminants in this way since they are defined as a determinant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is $\Delta_{K/\Bbb Q}(u)$ the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $u$? In that case we can argue as follows: Since $K$ has prime degree over $\Bbb Q$, we have $K=\Bbb Q(u)$, hence $\Bbb Z[u]$ is an order in $K$. We then know that $\pm \Delta_{K/\Bbb Q}(u)=\Delta(\Bbb Z[u])=\Delta(\mathcal{O}_K)(\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[u])^2$, hence $\Delta_K\mid\Delta_{K/\Bbb Q}(u)$

Comment: I don't know what an order is but from what I know, if I show that $\Bbb Z[u]$ is a additive subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K$ of finite index then the same reasoning would work, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the same reasoning would work

Comment: @leoli1 Thinking about it, why do we know that $u \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ to ensure that $K=\mathbb{Q}(u)$?

Comment: Because the only units in $\Bbb Q\cap \mathcal{O_K}=\Bbb Z$ are $\pm 1$ and they cannot be fundamental units.

Comment: True, I didn't remember that $\Bbb Q\cap \mathcal{O_K}=\Bbb Z$. Thank you!